# How can I delete the space at the end of a string in Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to remove the space at the end of a string.

For example, if I have a string `"text3 "` I want to delete that final space so that my string ends up as `"text3"`.

So far, I have tried using this method

```
${space_character} =     Set Variable    ${SPACE}
${desired_text} =    Remove String    ${desired_text} 
   ${space_character}
```

Where `${desired_text}` is initially just `"text3 "`. This doesn't seem to remove the space. Further I would like to only eliminate the final space character and nothing in between since I could have a `${desired_text}` which is equal to something like `"this is an example "`. Where the space at the end is what I want to remove, leaving only `"this is an example"`.

Answer (score 2):

Robot Framework is based on Python, and the string variables can use Python functions/methods directly.

In python we have `lstrip()`: removes characters from left, `rstrip()`: removes characters from right, and `strip()`: removes from both, left and right.
The default character to remove is the space.

An example of the use for your case, would be:

```
${desired_text}=    Set Variable    ${desired_text.rstrip()}
```

Comment: Hey Helio, thanks for the lead! I think this will work for me except that I believe this would remove all leading spaces, and I only want to delete one. Am I correct about this?

Comment: No, it only removes the one in the end.

Comment: String library has also Strip keyword you can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer with `rstrip()` is perfectly correct, that's the proper way to trim any whitespacing.

If the case is *(the special one that)* only a single space needs to be removed, this can be accomplished with some basic python trickery - check is the last character a space, and if so - reassign the variable to its value w/o the final char.

As strings in python are treated as list of characters, you can address and slice them as such. The list index operator (`[]`) supports a pointer to the *"last element of the list"* (`[-1]`), and the slicing supports *"return everything from the beginning to the semi-last"* (`[:-1]`).
With those two combined, this can be done with a simple reassignment operation:

```
IF    """${my string}"""[-1] == ' '
    ${my string}=    Set Variable   ${my string}[:-1]
END

# alternatively, on a single line:
${my string}=    Set Variable If   """${my string}"""[-1] == ' '   ${my string}[:-1]
  ...       ${my string}   # this is the "else" condition, e.g. what will be assigned of the last char is not a space - the variable's value w/o modification
```

Answer (score 0):

using the Replace String Using Regexp keyword

```
${new_text}=    String.Replace String Using Regexp    ${old_text}    \\s+    ${EMPTY}
```

Example

```
*** Settings ***
Library        String

*** Test Cases ***
TEST
    ${old_text}=    Set Variable        "TEST NAJA "
    Log        ${old_text}
    ${new_text}=    String.Replace String Using Regexp    ${desired_text}       \\s+     ${EMPTY}
    Log        ${new_text}
```